# Android: Id is not setting when the dispaly size is small

Tags: android, android-layout, android-imageview, android-7.0-nougat

I just try my application run in **Android N** having **display size small**.

My **layout.xml**

```
    <RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/layout_top"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:alpha="0.77"
    android:background="#000000" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/img_back"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_ham_menu" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtback"
        style="@style/textviewstyle_robotoRegular"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/img_back"
        android:text="@string/msgs_to_rj_heading"
        android:textColor="#CCFFFFFF"
        android:textSize="20sp" />



<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/img_alarm"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_marginRight="15dp"   
    android:src="@drawable/ic_timer_default"    
    android:visibility="visible" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

I am trying to refer the id for  having the id as "img_alarm"

```
img_alarm = (ImageView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.img_alarm);
```

When the Android N Display size is small the image is not showing in the UI , also the image ID is not setting.When we change the Display Size the  is shown in the UI and its id is set.

I am not getting why the  **is not showing** when the Display Size is small in Android N.

Am getting the error

> Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int android.widget.ImageView.getId()' on a null object reference

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity {org.radiomango.app/org.radiomango.app.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int android.widget.ImageView.getId()' on a null object reference
at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3385)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3425)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2698)
at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1445)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6044)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:865)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755)
 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int android.widget.ImageView.getId()' on a null object reference
at org.radiomango.app.HomeFragment.onResume(HomeFragment.java:322)
at android.app.Fragment.performResume(Fragment.java:2398)
at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1032)
at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1171)
at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1153)
at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchResume(FragmentManager.java:2049)
at android.app.FragmentController.dispatchResume(FragmentController.java:198)
at android.app.Activity.performResume(Activity.java:6783)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3362)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3425) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2698) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java) 
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1445) 
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6044) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:865) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755)
```

**Java**

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_home, container, false);
  img_alarm = (ImageView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.img_alarm);
}
@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
if (TimeSet == true) {
  img_alarm.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_timer_default);
} else {
  img_alarm.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_timer_active);
}
}
```

Is any changes need in layout for Display changes ??

Comment: Do you have any error message?

Comment: Your question is not clear. Please explain

Comment: updated the question with error message @Mande Kira

Comment: can you please check the error message , this happen when the Android N having Display Size is small @Jas

Comment: post your `org.radiomango.app.HomeFragment` code

Comment: yes. Post your code

Comment: Is small. What exact dimension did you use?

Comment: Are altering your layout programmatically?

Comment: when i debug I found that the Image id is not setting when display size is small @Ashish Ranjan

Comment: updates the question with java code @Jas

Comment: in Android N there is new feature called Display size, There we can control the Display size of the phone UI.Here the issue comes when the display size is small @Mande Kira

Comment: Where have you inflated your rootview layout??

Comment: updated the question with rootView @Jas

Comment: Aren't you getting error?? Where is your return statement of onCreateView?

Comment: Post your whole class. It is diffucult to track the problem otherwise

Comment: i got the solutions , In samll size of Display in Android N , we need layout-sw320dp. its not the issue of class file. @Jas

Answer (score -1):

Finally I got the solution In Android N when the display size is small we need a layout in res folder called **layout-sw320dp**.

Those layout having the issue copy to this layout. Then the issue is solved

Comment: That shouldn't be necessary unless you have an activity_home.xml defined in a layout directory with a high-order precedence that is missing the @id/img_alarm element. Or there could be some other issue with your code, but you definitely do not need to have an identical XML file layout-sw320dp just to support "small" display size.